In Inno Setup check if folder exist, if so rename the new folder
I want to make a installer for "unpacking" folders with files to a specific location – I done it with the Inno Setup wizard, but there is an issue because I would like to first check if folders with the name already exist, and if so rename the new ones:
Check if folder example exist in location – yes, rename new one to example_2 and put it into location –- no, put example into location.
I discovered in help file that there is a function int DirExists but no example etc. And I don't know how to use it properly :(

Use a scripted constant to implement unique destination path resolution with a use if DirExists support function:
[Files]
Source: "subdir\*"; DestDir: "{code:GetUniquePath}";

[Code]

var
  UniqueName: string;

function GetUniquePath(Param: string): string;
var
  BasePath: string;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if UniqueName = '' then
  begin
    I := 2;
    BasePath := ExpandConstant('{app}\subdir');
    UniqueName := BasePath;
    while DirExists(UniqueName) do
    begin
      UniqueName := BasePath + '_' + IntToStr(I);
      Inc(I);
    end;
    Log('Unique destination path resolved to: ' + UniqueName);
  end;
  Result := UniqueName;
end;

The above code resolves the path on the first call (for the first file in the subfolder). Some may rather prefer resolving the path in advance, like shown in this similar question:
In Inno Setup choose a directory to install files from a pre-defined set
